# Tracing spike/surge on ac/inverter circuit

Tags: power-supply, power, circuit-analysis, current

my friend has a sailing yacht with a 3000W inverter and a remote switch. When the ac circuit is switched to battery via the inverter all the dc powered navigation instruments power off before rebooting and resuming normal operations.

I have looked at the basic maths of the ac side and less than 1000W is on switched to take immediate power -eg fridge is plugged in and on but tv, kettle are off, some ac sockets may have random iPhone adapters plugged in adding to load but not consistently so don’t appear to be the source of the problem.

As my friend is neither electrically minded ( talk slowly I am a mechanical Engineer) or able bodied I have said I will try to determine the cause.

What is the best approach for investigating the issue, I have good practical electronics skills access to oscilloscope and multimeters signal generators etc but my experience is mostly building electronics projects and domestic electrical work not investigating this level of issue.

Comment: Inverter excessive inrush current.

Comment: Switch all the AC loads off, then switch to the inverter. Does the glitch still happen?

Comment: Thanks, that is some thing I have to investigate when I was on the boat I saw it happen but we were at sea and so didn’t want to be pulling the nav systems down . I have the vessel to my self next week so will investigate more thoroughly.